# C sscanf escaping input only if needed to?

Tags: c, file, date, scanf

I'm trying to read a date from a file which can be distorted or invalid. To test I am using sscanf to read line by line and to make sure there are three integers in each line by checking it's return value. So far I have this :

```
 #define NOERRORS 0
 #include <stdio.h>

int main (){

   FILE *pFile;
   char scanLine[80];
   int day = 0, month = 0, year = 0;

   // open file:
   pFile = fopen("dates.dat", "r");

   // while not end of file
   if(pFile != NULL)
   {
       // add each line to our array  
       while(fgets(scanLine, 80, pFile) != NULL)
       {
           printf("%s", scanLine);

           if(sscanf(scanLine, "%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d",
                    &day, &month, &year ) == 3)
           {
                printf("%d/%d/%d", day, month, year);
           }
           else
           {
               printf("Could Not read input\n");
           }
       }
       // close our file
       fclose(pFile);
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Can not open file");
   }
   return NOERRORS;
 }
```

My problem is that my expected escape sequence fails if the sequence does not match the file's content. How would you tackle this problem?

These tests will fail :

```
 4.12.3 // first character is a number
 fefwf453afaf // doesn't match the expected escape sequence.
 ee3r44 // doesn't match the expected escape sequence
```

Passes :

```
 dfdf5.5.5
 fsfwff3fewwev2vwvwvq1
```

Comment: What do you mean with "escape sequence"? There is only a newline in your code.

Comment: what i mean is that I'm trying to ignore anyhthing but ints in each line

Comment: `[^0-9]%d` in the format string means that there has to be a non-digit before the number, so it won't match a number at the beginning of the line. I suggest that you use a string-searching function to search for the first digit, and then call `sscanf` on the result of that.

Comment: "How would you tackle this problem?" ... I would clearly understand the grammar and write a simple parser.  sscanf probably isn't the right tool for the job, if you're looking for a robust solution.

Comment: You might comment your examples, please, which you *intend* to pass, and which you *intend* to fail.